# C# regex building

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have an encode string in my `C#` web app:

`&lt;a href=&quot;/product.aspx?zpid=564&quot;&gt;American Arborvitae &lt;/a&gt;-10 - 10<br />&lt;a href=&quot;/product.aspx?zpid=647&quot;&gt;Black Walnut &lt;/a&gt;-1 - 1<br />  <br />`

That is decoded to:

`"<a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=564\">American Arborvitae</a>-10 - 10<br /><a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=647\">Black Walnut </a>-1 - 1<br />  <br />"`

Is there a relatively easy way to use a `regex` to get the values between the `</a>-10 - 10<br />` and `</a>-1 - 1<br />`? I am not really the best at building regexes and I am not sure really how to define a pattern for something like this.  Or can the values be put into a string array easier? The number of entries can vary between like 1-30.

---- Use Case Per Request ----

The product page is a page for bulk amounts of trees. The user can enter whatever number for the amount they want (cap at 1000). There can be anywhere between 1-30 different trees depending on the season and time of the year.

Comment: Hi, what exactly is your use case? :)

Comment: I don't see how the first string is decoded to what you mentioned... And there's no `</a>-0 - 0<br />` in the string? Or you mean `</a>-1 - 1<br />`? Can the numbers change? Something like [that](http://regex101.com/r/oF5oV5)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mean to use 1 instead of 0. The numbers can be what ever number the user enters, I think they are capped at 1000 though.

Comment: @Jerry, replacing the numbers with `\d` would suffice correct? But how would that get me all of the values that I would need?

Comment: @Brett Oh, you wanted the part between `</a>` and `<br />`? I had thought you meant between the big part `</a>-10 - 10<br />` and `</a>-1 - 1<br />`, meaning you wanted `<a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=647\">Black Walnut `. But yea, you can use `\d`, and more precisely `\d+` to allow for larger numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex("</a>(.*?)<br />");
var matches = regex.Matches("<a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=564\">American Arborvitae</a>-10 - 10<br /><a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=647\">Black Walnut </a>-1 - 1<br /> <br />");
foreach (Match match in matches)
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

-10 - 10
-1 - 1

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex will match on `</a>-0 - 0<br />` through `</a>-99 - 99<br />` so it should handle the number of items you're expecting:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"</a>-\d{1,2}\s-\s\d{1,2}<br\s*/>");
```

You can use it to get an array of strings like this:

```
var parts = rx.Split("<a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=564\">American Arborvitae</a>-10 - 10<br /><a href=\"/product.aspx?zpid=647\">Black Walnut </a>-1 - 1<br /> <br />");
```

And the result will be:

```
    <a href="/product.aspx?zpid=564">American Arborvitae
    <a href="/product.aspx?zpid=647">Black Walnut
     <br />
```

The rest is up to you. Hope this helps!